# How to set filename containing spaces in Content-Disposition header

Tags: java, servlets, download, filenames

I have this piece of code:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

When the file name is "a_b_c.doc" or "abc.doc" the name of the downloaded file is displayed correctly. However, when the file name is "a b c .doc" the name of the downloaded file is only "a".

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 90):

Use quotes:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

Comment: what if the filename has " in it ? (it is not possible in windows but linux files may have '"' in their name.)

Comment: This is THE correct way (filename value as quoted string) according to HTTP 1.1 spec: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1

Answer (score 17):

According to [the HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2) you surround the string with double-quotes, and escape any quotes or backslashes within by preceding them with a single backslash.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Very \"interesting\" file \\ files.txt"
```

This will prompt to save as `Very "interesting" file \ files.txt`.  Note that the presence of a backslash does not suggest a folder, it suggests the backslash is part of the filename (which is perfectly valid on Linux and some other platforms, but not on Windows.)

Answer (score 2):

Following steps are required:

- **URI-encode** the filename
- **Replace the spaces** in the encoded filename (we're using an URL encoder instead of URI encoder, but URL encoding uses `+` as encoded space instead of `%20`, so we need to manually replace them with `%20`).
- **Set the encoded file name in the header**. Here we have two variants: one which specifices the encoding, and one that doesn't. For maximal compatibility we can specify both.

Code:

```
String fileName = ...;
String encodedFileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, 
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()).replace("+", "%20");

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    String.format("inline; filename*=UTF-8''%1$s; filename=%1$s", encodedFileName));
```

Example header:
`inline; filename*=UTF-8''Hello%20World.doc; filename=Hello%20World.doc`

Successfully tested with

- Firefox ✔
- Chrome ✔
- Edge ✔
- Internet Explorer ✔

Comment: unfortunately, doesn't work in Safari properly. You have to only have filename* or pass utf-8 name in plain `filename` part for Safari only

Answer (score 0):

if you quote your filename with `chr(34)` it will work:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + chr(34) + fileName + chr(34));
```

Comment: `chr(34)` is there in PHP but this is a Java question and this does not work in Java. In Java, you would need to do `(char) 34` instead. But come on guys, this code is not readable unless you have the ASCII table in your head. Why not just use double quotes when you need double quotes? Of course, you need to escape them, i.e. put a backslash in front of it like in `"this is my \"quoted\" string"`. This is more readable and works the same in Java, PHP, C++, ...