# gsutil setmeta: quotes and spaces within "Content-Disposition" metadata

Tags: gsutil

I'm using `gsutil setmeta` to set a custom filename for downloading, by means of `Content-Disposition` property (`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"; filename*="filename.jpg"`).

Filenames must be enclosed in quotes. And also the argument of `setmeta` has its own quotes.

If I do

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Myname.jpg"; filename*="Myname.jpg"" gs://<path-to-file>"
```

is ok, unless the file name I specify in the metadata contains spaces (e.g. `filename="My name.jpg"`): in this case, I get an error. Is there a way to escape the quotes, or else a way to have spaces within the download filename?

Single quotes seems not to be an option (they are shown in the file name when I download it).

EDIT:
I tried replacing spaces with `%20` (cf. [How to set filename containing spaces in Content-Disposition header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634337/how-to-set-filename-containing-spaces-in-content-disposition-header)). It's a step forward: gsutil does the job, and if I download the file with Chrome it's ok. But if I use Safari to download the file, the `%20` are literaly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surround the filename in double quotes and escape any inner quotes within the filename to set a custom filename for downloading using `gsutil` and the `Content-Disposition` metadata. Replace any spaces in the filename with `%20` to comply with URL encoding.

Here's an illustration:

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"My name.jpg\"; filename*=utf-8''My%20name.jpg" gs://<path-to-file>
```

This eliminates issues when setting a filename that contains spaces. The correct filename, "My name.jpg," without any visible quotations, will show in the downloaded image.